# Using Django forms to get information from more than 1 model

Tags: django, forms, linktable

I am using Django to create a gym app. In this app users can share workouts that have various exercises in them. I have three models:

- **Workout** ( which stores the names of the different workouts and the author of the post and time of creation),
- **Exercise** ( which stores the name of the exercises and a description of each)
- **WorkoutExercises** ( which links an exercise to a workout and stores the number of sets and reps).

Currently, I am trying to make a form that will allow a user to create a workout and add exercises to it (each with various sets and reps). However, I have found that I cannot use more than 1 model in my Form. How do I go about getting information from the user, so I can put it in the database so that it all links up?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail code and error... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)